# Problemas al recuperar la longitud de un vector (.lenght)

Tags: java

actualmente me encuentro con la siguiente situación en mi programa principal:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner wen= new Scanner(System.in);

        int numeroCuenta;
        int i;
        System.out.println("BIENVENIDO! ");
        System.out.println("Favor ingrese  el número de cuenta ");
        numeroCuenta=wen.nextInt();

        int vector[] = new int[5];


        if(numeroCuenta == vector.length) {
            System.out.println ("NIP aceptado:"+numeroCuenta);
        } else {
            System.out.println ("El numero  debe tener  5 digitos");
        }                  
    }
```

¿Porque motivo no puedo recuperar "vector.length"?
Gracias de antemano.
Saludos.

Comment: Te parece adecuado ese titulo? por favor mejoralo, y para ello te recomiendo leer las reglas de [ask], ademas en SO no debes mostrar el codigo como imagen sino como texto.

Comment: ok gracias, que pena

Comment: No hay problema, solo lee las reglas y corrige tus errores.

Comment: Muestra el codigo como texto, no nos gustan que muestren el codigo como texto ya que nosotros deseamos copiar y testear su codigo.

Comment: ¿Cómo es que no lee ? no está muy clara su pregunta . tal y como está debería funcionar , entraría al if si ingresa 5 por teclado.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no te hace bien??

Answer (score 1):

El problema que veo es que estas comparando un numero de tipo Integer tal que "12345" con un length de 5 y por eso nunca te funciona. Si metieras un 5 sólo te entraría en el if y te aceptaría el NIP. Pero supongo que no es lo que quieres, por lo que prueba el siguiente código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner wen= new Scanner(System.in);

        int numeroCuenta;
        int i;
        System.out.println("BIENVENIDO! ");
        System.out.println("Favor ingrese  el número de cuenta ");
        numeroCuenta=wen.nextInt();

        int vector[] = new int[5];

        String num = numeroCuenta +"";

        if(num.length() == vector.length) {
            System.out.println ("NIP aceptado:"+numeroCuenta);
        } else {
            System.out.println ("El numero  debe tener  5 digitos");
        }  

    }
```

Comment: Gracias, esta perfecto.